# Box-shadow overflow issue

Tags: z-index, css

I have two boxes, title and content. I am using box-shadow on these to make them more good looking. Right now, both shadows are visible one on top of the other. But i want the title shadow not to float over the content box.

If i add **position: relative** to the title box, the content shadow stops floating over the title (this is exactly what i want to do, but the other way around). However, trying the opposite doesn't work. Z-index also doesnt seem to be working.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JR93S/24/

```
h2 {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 5px 11px 5px 11px;

    border-radius: 3px;

    color: #333;
    background-color: #CCF;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

    border: 1px solid #999;

    border-radius: 3px;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

<h2>title</h2>
<div>some stuff here</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `inset` box-shadows to avoid overlap.

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/JR93S/25/

**EDIT**

I guess this is the effect you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/JR93S/31/

Comment: but i want the shadows to be on the outside

Comment: Yes your edited answer is the one i want. The only problem is that i would have to do a lot of editing to the pages to include a wrapper in every case. So i would rather avoid it. I have updated the fiddle to include positioning and z-index: http://jsfiddle.net/JR93S/32/ but it doesn't work. Isnt there a way i could do this without a wrapper? Since it works one way, im sure it must work the other way too?

Comment: A relatively positioned element would allow absolute positioning of elements inside it. So, that wrapper has to be included. Im afraid thats how z-index works :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the trick with this was to add...

```
background-color: #FFF;
```

...to the div. Now z-index works.